# Get SQL table data for current month using prepared statement PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is a code which I am using to get current month data from table `wp_formdata`

HTML :

```
<div class="result" id="result" name="result">

            <?php echo $head1; ?> <?php echo $out; ?> <?php echo $head2; ?> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['result_options'] == 'Current_Month') {   

    $now = new \DateTime('now');
    $CurrMonth = $now->format('m');
    $CurrYear = $now->format('Y');

    $sql ="Select date,select_bank,entry_type,income_cat,expense_cat,amount,expense_cat_sub from wp_formdata WHERE MONTH(?) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(?) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) order by date ";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
        $message =  '<h1 style="color:red;padding-top:5%;">SQL Error !!</h1>';

    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss", $CurrMonth, $CurrYear);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $out = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $out .= "<tr><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".$row["select_bank"]."</td><td>".$row["entry_type"]."</td><td>".$row["income_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat"]."</td><td>".$row["expense_cat_sub"]."</td><td>".$row["amount"]."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

I verified the database connection and it's working as expected. I also verified the variable `$CurrMonth` and `$CurrYear` values:

```
echo $CurrMonth; //will give output 10 

echo $CurrYear;  //will give output 2018
```

But I am not getting any search result. Any suggestions to resolve it?

Comment: You may need to do `ii` instead of `ss` inside `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` as the month and year are numeric not string values. That aside, have you tried running the query directly against mysql to confirm it works OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month and year comparison in your SQL looks incorrect, you are comparing the current month (and extracting the month from it `MONTH(?)`) with the month of the current date (`MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())`).  You can get away without using any parameters as you need to compare (I assume) the month of the date from the record (`MONTH(date)`) with the current month (same for year).

```
$sql ="Select date,select_bank,entry_type,income_cat,expense_cat,
                 amount,expense_cat_sub 
          from wp_formdata 
          WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                   AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
          order by date ";
```

It's always worth checking SQL out in something like PHPMyAdmin to ensure it gives the results your after before running it in PHP.

In case you need to do this for any other month, you can use parameters, but don't extract the month from it...

```
$sql ="Select date,select_bank,entry_type,income_cat,expense_cat,
                 amount,expense_cat_sub 
          from wp_formdata 
          WHERE MONTH(date) = ?
                   AND YEAR(date) = ?
          order by date ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. Earlier I was using this code and then I came to know about sql injection and methods to prevent it. I have some other inputs fields part of a drop drown menu. I am trying to use same format for all of my php codes. Is above method safe  from sql injection? sorry I am new to php and mysql and trying to understand it

Comment: The first method doesn't use any parameters so there is no possibility of SQL injection.  The second one is as safe as any SQL when using bound variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the PHP current date to the DB current date.

In your SQL string you should replace `MONTH(?)` and `YEAR(?)` with `MONTH(date)` and `YEAR(date)`.
At this point you should remove the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss", $CurrMonth, $CurrYear);` because the SQL string has not parameters.